# How do I use Oracle regular expression to separate text by '\R\'?

Tags: regex, oracle

I'd like to execute for~loop using the \R\ delimiter.

```
DECLARE
    v_idx NUMBER := 1;
    v_text VARCHAR2(1000);
    v_pattern VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
    v_text := 'GR105^INF^191097-1^CT^test string r01\R\GR109^INF^191097-2^CR^test string r02 (1234)';
    v_pattern := '\\R\\';

    FOR repeat IN (SELECT trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_text, v_pattern, 1, LEVEL)) item
                   FROM dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(v_text, v_pattern))

    LOOP
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('--------------- ' || v_idx ||  ' ---------------');
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_a = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 1)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_b = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 2)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_c = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 3)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_d = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 4)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_e = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 5)));
        v_idx := v_idx + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It works fine with '~' separator and '[^~]+' pattern.
But I don't know how to use '\R\'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only matching the delimiter `\R\` and not the preceding sub-string. To match the preceding sub-string you can match `(.*?)(\\R\\|$)` and extract the contents of the first capturing group:

```sql
DECLARE
    v_idx NUMBER := 1;
    v_text VARCHAR2(1000);
    v_pattern VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
    v_text := 'GR105^INF^191097-1^CT^test string r01\R\GR109^INF^191097-2^CR^test string r02 (1234)';
    v_pattern := '(.*?)(\\R\\|$)';

    FOR repeat IN (SELECT trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_text, v_pattern, 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)) item
                   FROM dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT(v_text, v_pattern))

    LOOP
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('--------------- ' || v_idx ||  ' ---------------');
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_a = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 1)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_b = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 2)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_c = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 3)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_d = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 4)));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('v_e = ' || trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(repeat.item, '[^^]+', 1, 5)));
        v_idx := v_idx + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Note: `LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(v_text, v_pattern)` needs to change to `LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT(v_text, v_pattern)` as there will be a final zero-width match from the pattern (on `.*?$`) that needs to be ignored.*

Which outputs:

```
--------------- 1 ---------------
v_a = GR105
v_b = INF
v_c = 191097-1
v_d = CT
v_e = test string r01
--------------- 2 ---------------
v_a = GR109
v_b = INF
v_c = 191097-2
v_d = CR
v_e = test string r02 (1234)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R7-8aExf)

Comment: Thank you. One more question. How I get the value with delimiter(\F\) `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('INF\F\2\F\3\F\4\F\5', '(.*?)(\\F\\|$)', 1, 1) as data FROM dual;` This command return with delimier like 'INF\F\'

Comment: @EddieVedder Exactly as shown in the answer. Use the 6th argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to specify which capturing group you want to return.